# Meaning of TEMPLATE=aux in a qmake project file

Tags: qmake

What does this line mean in qmake .pro file?

```
TEMPLATE=aux
```

It is [not documented](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#template), but seems to not cause an error or anything now that I tested it, and I've seen it used in a .pro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google returns "- Implemented "aux" template that allows making use of the INSTALLS variable
      without building anything. Needed for projects with QML entry point." From [Digia's 4.8 release notes](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/plain/dist/changes-4.8.0).

Also of interest: [the patch which added this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?id=bc88f528dcfe3b2b2369530d76fee2994c2887f9).

Comment: Also of interest: [the patch which added the documentation](https://gitlab.com/pteam/pteam-qtbase/commit/3a9763d3492ef9c26a63c86e8a024fab3ce5807a) for the aux template.

Answer (score 4):

The TEMPLATE variable's value of aux is now documented at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#template .

I have seen TEMPLATE = aux used in .pro files for Qt Installer Frameworks projects which create standalone executables which do not have to be run from Qt Creator.